# Valgrind error on Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value

Tags: c++11, gcc, valgrind

This is my code for accepting only integers in my project:

```
int getInt(
       const char* prompt = nullptr  // User entry prompt
);
```

***Definition:***

```
 int getInt(const char* prompt)
   {
       bool error1, error2;
       int intg;
       char c;
       if (prompt)cout << prompt;
       do
       {
           error1 = false;
           error2 = false;
           cin >> intg;
           error2 = cin.fail();
           cin.get(c);
           error1 = c != '\n';
           if (error2)
           {
               cin.clear();
               clearinput();
               cout << "Bad integer value, try again: ";
           }
           else if (error1)
           {
               cin.clear();
               clearinput();
               cout << "Enter only an integer, try again: ";
           }
       } while (error1 || error2);
       return intg;
   }
```

I have a default value of "nullptr" for my prompt but still Valgrind showing this error, it is with `--track-origins=yes`

```
==161949== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==161949==    at 0x402599: sdds::getInt(char const*) (utils.cpp:55)
==161949==    by 0x40116F: getIntTester() (ms1Tester_prof.cpp:35)
==161949==    by 0x401065: main (ms1Tester_prof.cpp:19)
==161949==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==161949==    at 0x4024C4: sdds::getInt(char const*) (utils.cpp:49)
==161949==
```

***Update:*** initializing the `char c` fixed the problem.

Comment: Which are lines 49 and 55?

Comment: What happens if `cin.get(c)` fails?  Or if `cin >> intg;` fails?

Comment: Line 49 is the open bracket for function definition and line 55 is an open bracket for the `do-while` loop.

Comment: if `cin >> intg;` fails error2 will be true and loop for another entry, `cin.get(c)` will be either '\n' or another character, if it is another character error1 will be true, the only input I accept is an integer followed by a '\n'.

Comment: Nope, if `cin.get(c)` fails then `c` is left unchanged, which means it can stay uninitialized.  So the subsequent `c != '\n'` may account for your "uninitialized value" error.  (It's also a logic bug as the uninitialized value of `c` might coincidentally be `'\n'`; more generally, it's potentially undefined behavior.)

Comment: I agree you won't get an uninitialized value from the failure of `cin >> intg;`, but if an I/O error or EOF occurs then it will probably continue to occur every time, and you will loop infinitely making no progress.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you, initializing the `char c` was indeed the issue.

Comment: Great.  You can post that as an answer and accept it.